# How to start Oracle 11g automatically using script on Fedora 23?

Tags: linux, oracle, redhat, sqlplus, fedora

I have installed Oracle 11g on my Fedora 23 Virtualbox ,each time I want to start Oracle I have to start

`sqlplus '/as sysdba'` then type `startup` and then exit and then type 
 `lsnrctl start` and then again type `emctl start dbconsole` ...how to automate this using a script or any alternative way but I prefer script once my server start ...I'm also not able to connect to my server from outside the virtual machine.

thanks in advance

Comment: Try this https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=oracle11g&f=5

Comment: I did the script you mentioned only `emctl` & `dbconsole` are starting ...I still have to type `sqlplus  '/as sysdba'` then type `startup`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a systemd `.service` unit file. I don't think there is an official one, but [this oracle forum post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4011700) contains an example for Fedora 25 Server. You can find more information about writing `.service` files here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15348/writing-basic-systemd-service-files